Weird Lines on Cycles Render
I'm pretty new to Cycles rendering and have been experimenting with it. I just rendered this robot, but as you can see, there are strange lines all over the glass texture and the first part of the limbs. I'm sure it's a lighting issue, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing it. Can anyone help?



The issue is that your object's geometry wasn't half of the whole object. In this example, I removed one half of the geometry and then used a Mirror Modifier. Notice how it mirrors the object on the Y-axis, making it symmetrically whole. In your case, the object was already symmetrically whole, so adding the Mirror Modifier created an overlapping mirrored copy. Additionally, with the X-axis option selected, it mirrored the object again on the X-axis, causing another set of overlapping vertices. For more information on mirror overlaps, see this thread.

